# Convergence of measures with Følner sequence (in Amenable group)

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

We say that the group $G$ is  amenable, if it admits a Følner sequence, that is a sequence of finite sets $\{F_n\}\subseteq G$ such that

\begin{equation*}
\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{|gF_n\Delta F_n|}{|F_n|}=0, \forall g\in G
\end{equation*}

Also let $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ be a continuous action of discrete group $G$ on compact metric space $(X, d)$.

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $X$ and define $\varphi_g^*(\mu)(A)= \mu(\varphi_{g^{-1}}(A)$.

Take 
\begin{equation*}
\nu_n= \frac{\Sigma_{t\in F_n}\varphi_t^*(\mu)}{|F_n|},
\end{equation*}
In my research I need to know relation between $\lim_{n\to \infty}\nu_n(\varphi(g^{-1}, A)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\nu_n(A)$.

Can I say that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Sigma_{t\in F_n}\varphi_t^*(\mu)}{|F_n|}= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Sigma_{t\in gF_n}\varphi_t^*(\mu)}{|F_n|}?
\end{equation*}
In the following I try to give a proof for it:

We have $gF_n\subseteq F_n\cup gF_n\Delta F_n$ and $F_n\subseteq gF_n\cup F_n\Delta gF_n$, hence we have:

\begin{equation*}
\bigcup _{t\in gF_n}\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A)\subseteq \bigcup _{t\in F_n}\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A)\cup \bigcup _{t\in gF_n\Delta F_n}\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A)
\end{equation*}
And 
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup _{t\in F_n}\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A)\subseteq \bigcup _{t\in gF_n}\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A)\cup \bigcup _{t\in gF_n\Delta F_n}\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A)
\end{equation*}
Hence we can say that 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\Sigma_{t\in gF_n}\mu(\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A))}{|F_n|}\leq \frac{\Sigma_{t\in F_n}\mu(\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A))}{|F_n|}+ \frac{\Sigma_{t\in gF_n\Delta F_n}\mu(\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A))}{|F_n|}
\end{equation*}

and 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\Sigma_{t\in F_n}\mu(\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A))}{|F_n|}\leq \frac{\Sigma_{t\in gF_n}\mu(\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A))}{|F_n|}+ \frac{\Sigma_{t\in gF_n\Delta F_n}\mu(\varphi_{t^{-1}}(A))}{|F_n|}
\end{equation*}
By propobability of $\mu$ and 
\begin{equation*}
\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{|gF_n\Delta F_n|}{|F_n|}=0, \forall g\in G
\end{equation*}

as $n\to \infty$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Sigma_{t\in F_n}\varphi_t^*(\mu)}{|F_n|}= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Sigma_{t\in gF_n}\varphi_t^*(\mu)}{|F_n|}?
\end{equation*}
Please help me to know that my proof is true or not?

Comment: Note that the definition you provide is only valid for countable groups. No uncountable group admits a sequence $(F_n)$ as prescribed.

Comment: @YCor, yes, $G$ is a countable group, can you help me please?